# PCH chip getting Hot, motherboard not booting/posting?

Tags: boot, motherboard

I have built a simple Linux PC, using an asrock-h81m-hds, and an I3, 1150, 
the PC refuses to boot and just spins the fans, the hard drive spins up but thats about it, I noticed that the PCH is getting rather hot during this process, what could be a possible cause of this, or are there to many possible causes?

Answer (score 0):

Well, hard to answer but a black screen (100% black) means that the BIOS Post did not complete. That means that one (or several) of the components are not working correctly. That could have several reasons.
The typical reasons are:

- Missing power (GPU, CPU, Motherboard)
- RAM broken or not plugged in correctly
- CPU not plugged in correctly
- GPU not plugged in correctly

Try to find a speaker and plug it onto your mainboard. You should hear error codes or Post-codes. Then google those beeb-codes (like short-short-long or similar)

Comment: Thank you! I hear beeps, but they appear to be coming from the HardDrive? At least, thats what it sounds like.

Comment: Unplug the hard drive and any other drive. YOu should be able to see something on your screen with no drives attached.

Comment: I will try that and report back.

Comment: nope, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Then I guess that something is broken.